# ESP32 programming & EN delay circuits

Tags: circuit-design, pcb-design, esp32

Can you help me verify this schematic which:

- creates the `EN` pin delay circuit using recommended R&C values from Espressif
- adds ESD diode, as recommended by Espressif
- adds decouple/bypass capacitors using recommended values from Espressif
- adds RTS/DTR circuit which should change boot mode when programmer is connected

for any mistakes or possible ESP32 stability problems

Programmer pins will connect directly to lines: **RTS, DTR, TX, RX, PWR_GND, PWR_3V3**

[ESP32-C6-WROOM datasheet](https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32-c6-wroom-1_wroom-1u_datasheet_en.pdf)  pages 13,30

Schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Comment: The note says "GPIO8 - Always pull up", but you have it pulled down.

Comment: If you are going to be using the serial and the wifi, you'll probably need more capacitance.  Look online, there are lots of blogs and videos showing the supply line dropping as those peripherals are used.  I think I added a 10uF to mine.

Comment: @Aaron can you link something? are you sure that happens with a proper power supply like the one used?

Comment: A quick google search returned this. This is for ESP8266, but the 32 isn't that much different for power: https://youtu.be/wf_msvWv1jk around the 5 minute mark he shows live scope traces.

Comment: Are you sure about the pull down? Looking at [this article](https://eepower.com/resistor-guide/resistor-applications/pull-up-resistor-pull-down-resistor/#) it seems to be a pull-up, where a pull-down would have resistor on the other side instead

Comment: The pull up article you linked is correct.  Your circuit is not.  You have GPIO8->4.7kΩ->3.3V, this is a correct pull up.  **BUT** there is also a connection GPIO8->0Ω->Gnd.  This is a *very* strong pull down.  The article has a switch between the I/O and Gnd, your circuit has a direct connection.

Comment: I see. So the proper pull-up would be to just leave the GPIO8->4.7k->3.3V part, and remove the rest

Comment: That is correct

Comment: @Aaron I misread the docs. The correct schematic is on page 32 so the recommended values are 22uF and 0.1uF. So it's above 10uF and should be fine.

Comment: do I need a third - decoupling - capacitor with this power supply? power supply is not covered by Espressif schematic

Comment: I think that 22uF is big enough to cover everything, correct me if I am wrong